# How to disable AltGr in Win7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout

I am supporting a user that can't type and consequently often hits <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (on the right side of space-key). He has enough power to decide he wants to disable that key (instead of learning to type). and he asked me to quickly get rid of that key

The only way I found was using KbdEdit and map <kbd>AltGr</kbd> to "KANA" ([How to](http://www.kbdedit.com/manual/ex13_replacing_altgr_with_kana.html)) but unfortunately that does not behave as promised. I am waiting for support from the developer, but thought that meanwhile I should see if anyone of you has better suggestion how to address this.

Comment: get something pointy and painful enough to stick on his altgr key. that way he'll learn not to press it.

Comment: Use an app like SharpKeys to map the key to an unused one such as F12 for example.

Comment: Znau, great suggestion, but I have feeling my user won't be happy with that.

Comment: There is also possibility to turn off `AltGr` by a keyboard filter driver.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com):

> SharpKeys is a Registry hack that is used to make certain keys on a
>   keyboard act like other keys. For example, if you accidentally hit
>   Caps Lock often, you could use this utility to map Caps Lock to a
>   Shift key or even turn it off completely. This official release
>   includes support for up to 104 mappings, an extensive list of
>   available keys, and a "Type Key" option to help when managing
>   mappings.

I have not used it personally, but know someone who has used it in the past and is quite happy with it.

Comment: I have used it on XP+ and recommend it. Since all utils of this type are simply GUIs for editing the existing ScancodeMap value in the registry, there's no need to keep them running like an AHK script.

Comment: That sounded like exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Unfortunately two probs: NOD32-Antivir wouldn't let me go to the site. So I got it from here instead: http://sharpkeys.en.softonic.com/

Now, it cannot just "disable AltGr", so I tried to disable keystrokes such as AltGr+Q (wich create @ on my german kbd). But SharpKeys complained about not recognizing that keystroke - and it did the same for all other AltGr-Combos I tried :((
'

Comment: @MBaas: Did you try what I suggested in my comment above, i.e. to remap the key to an ordinarily unused/rarely used one?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the problem is not pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, but <kbd>AltGr</kbd> in combination with other keys?

You might want to get [The Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx).

There you `Load existing Keyboard...` (from File-Menu), select the language and design your user prefers, delete any bindings to keys with the `Shift states` of <kbd>AltGr</kbd>. Then you `Build DLL and Setup Package` (from Project-Menu) and afterwards install your individual keyboard design to the target machine.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a hardware solution? Physically remove the key.

Comment: sure. remotely turn off the tv: slingshot a hammer.

Comment: The keys on many types of keyboards snap in and out. Sure, on a laptop or Chiclet type keyboard it won't work so well, but this isn't intended as a blowtorch and jackhammer type of solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. MS KLC was also an idea I considered, but as I only wanted to disable that simple key, it seemed too much work to create a separate layout etc.
I finally found "keytweak" (here: http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/ ) and that has an easy switch "disable key" which quickly fixed the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the [keymapper](https://code.google.com/p/keymapper/) program to accomplish this. It lets you remap and disable keyboard keys using a virtual keyboard.